# Update a composer package dependencies.. dependencies during development

Tags: php, composer-php

Here is one thing I've been struggling with for a while now.

Let's take a scenario.

You need to create a new feature for package x. Package x is part of a larger project made up of many packages. So when you're adding stuff to package x, you work locally within the vendor folder on our project - so you can see your chances reflected in the overall project environment.

During development you figure out it would be better to split some of the code out in a separate package. So you create a package y for this sole purpose. Now you add it to composer.json within package x as a dependency, so composer knows to require & autoload this new package.

Buuut. How do one move forward with development on package x using package y without having to some some shady stuff such as adding the package temporarily to the main project so that a composer update require & autoload the new package?

-

The above example really comes into existence once you split development between parties. If i start a new feature branch on package x, make package y & add package y as a dependency. Then when the next person that needs to do something on package x within the same branch get's a reference error because composer didn't require this new package for this person. This happen because that next person goes into the vendor folder, find the package & manually checking out that feature branch, expecting to be able to do their work from there on out.

Is there any alternative? Am i doing thing wrong? Having a hard time finding any useful information for these workflows.

Comment: `So when you're adding stuff to package x, you work locally within the vendor folder on our project` Wat? No, you should develop your package x completely independently of the main project environment, otherwise it isn't a separate package, it's a part of the main project

Comment: @MarkBaker I do that for some of the packages. But sometimes it's just easier to work directly within the package when i have a task to fix a issue with something very specific within an actual project. Where the variables of triggering this glitch relates to the data & communication between packages. This way i can see my changes take effect straight away - without having to try & recreate the scenario or glitch within a managed environment within the package. But this might be where i go wrong. It just saved time during development.

Comment: Easier !== better; if you're changing the public methods or api for package x, then you should be testing it in isolation before making the changes to the main project that call package x.... separation of concerns and all that

Comment: @MarkBaker You're amazing. You're so right. If i could run my package separate from the main project. Then package x becomes the root of the project & doing composer update within package x would require & autoload the new package.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to composer update the main project to pull in the new version of package x once you'd made the changes to package x, tested  and committed them, but that also makes version management and tagging of package x easier